# Setting up database for e2e testing fails: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, chai

I am having some troubles trying to set up a database for testing purposes. The data stored in the database should be removed an re-populated for each test. I am currently doing the following:

*db.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// a Mongoose model describing an entity
const Entity = require('entity-model');

// entities.mock is an array containing entity objects.
const mockedEntities= require('./entities.mock');

function setUp() {
  Entities.collection.insertMany(mockedEntities);
}

function breakDown() {
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
  });
}

module.exports = { setUp, breakDown };
```

Then in my *test.js*:

```
const db = require('./db');

describe('e2e tests to make sure all endpoints return the correct data from the database', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db.breakDown();
    db.setUp();
  });

  it('should check store-test-result (UR-101)', (done) => ...perform test);
  it('should check store-nirs-device (UR-102)', (done) => ...perform test);
});
```

It seems like I am not emptying out the database before re-populating it correctly. Any advise as to what could be the cause?

Comment: Could you please show us data that you're injecting !! Did you check if there is any issue with the data ? Something like unique fields not getting proper values on all documents

Comment: @srinivasy the data is correct. The first test actually runs properly. Removing the data and re-populating really seems to be the issue.

Comment: I think the problem with your original code is having a callback inside async/await which wouldn't work like that i.e; it doesn't wait until breakdown is done, it would call that func and proceed on, You can have same code & wrap that func with :: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`, as your code in question is clean with code divided in func's which is better in complex logic implementations !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await MyEntity.collection.drop();
    await MyEntity.collection.insertMany(mockedMyEntity);
  });
```

This solved my issue.

In case this result in an Mongo Error ns not found you need to explicitly create the collection in the database before dropping it. This happens if the collection does not exist. You can do this by adding a before:

```
before(async () => {
    await MyEntity.createCollection();
  });
```

Do not set option: autoCreate to true in you model as this should not be set to false in production according to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoCreate.